# How to remove a muted attribute in a website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

Here iam opening a website which has several videos and all videos when playing are set by default to `muted` in the video tag.Example is given here

```
<video id="pbotplayer_html5_api" class="vjs-tech" poster="https://somename_1.jpg" muted="" preload="auto" autoplay="" loop="" src="https://somename_1.mp4" __idm_id__="-1787736063" controls=""><source src="https://somename_1.mp4" type="video/mp4"><p class="vjs-no-js"></a></p></video>
```

From this we can clearly see that the `muted attribute` is enabled by default and iam visiting this website in chrome.And i have even disabled `Flash player` in `chrome://plugins` but it does not work.

So all i wanted is to remove this muted attribute when ever a new video form this plays and there are large number of videos in this site and it is not easy to increase slide each time.

Here iam attaching how the controls look like.[image]

We can see that the volume slider is 0 and each and every time we need to increase the slider,but manually it is difficult.

So any solution to this problem either by writing an script which runs everytime the webpage loads new video and it removes the `muted` attribute.

Comment: Good question..

Comment: The muted attribute does not contain any value

Comment: **$("video").removeAttr("muted");** try this one it will remove attribute muted from all the video elements and put this in document.ready function

Comment: @Curiousdev But the problem is he dont have any code or any extesntion

Comment: is this on something you're coding, or a 3rd party site and you just want a browser helper? if the latter then SuperUser is probably a better place to ask this (but as @Curiousdev noted you could write a Chrome extension to run that on the site)

Comment: Ohh ohkk if you are using google chrome there is an extension of chrome is **custom javascript** install this and add above code I have commented above it will run automatically when page loads just like document ready u just have to install that extension for chrome add this line it will save for the current domain also. Whenever you domain's any of page called this block of code will run on page load using this extension here is a [link]( https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija)

Answer (score 1):

try with the following:

```
$("#video-id").removeAttr("muted");
```

this will remove the muted attribute of the targeted video, but you will need to run this code everytime you update it.